# Is there a way in svelte where I can put the calendar icon inside input field? And, how can I change the color of the calendar?

Tags: javascript, web, web-applications, desktop, svelte

This is my code: 
https://svelte.dev/repl/f137b909d3e740f99a030576189091db?version=3.22.3
How can I the calendar icon inside input field? And, how can I change the color of the calendar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a 3rd party component and a quick look at their documentation tells me, that it does not support custom placement of the icon.

https://svelte-mui.now.sh/datepicker/datefield

Changing the color was a bit tricky to figure out. They use global css variables, and I'd do it like this. Add the following snippet to your App.svelte:

```
<style>
    :global(:root) {
        --primary: red;
    }
</style>
```

There are more global variables, that you could overwrite. See their example:

https://github.com/vikignt/svelte-mui/blob/master/example/assets/global.css